# Change AD Users password overriding password complexity policy

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, passwords, account

One of our accounts used a simple password of lets say apple, but has been reset by someone and now we need to change the user's password back to apple.

We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 and this password fails the password complexity so it will not allow it. The account has to have this password as it is used by another software in the domain. I have tried changing the default domain policy password - Password must meet complexity requirements to disabled but this has no effect.

Is there another way to change the account password? 3rd party software or another method anyone knows of?

Answer (score 0):

Is this account a Windows domain account? If so, there's nothing you can do from SQL Server. All account properties are managed by Windows AD policies. SQL Server is a trusting party and has no ability to make changes.

If it's a SQL Server login, then you first need to disable the "Enforce password policy" option then change the login's password. You can do it from the SSMS GUI or via TSQL:

```
USE master
GO

ALTER LOGIN [lowsecuser] WITH CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_policy=OFF
GO

ALTER LOGIN [lowsecuser] 
WITH PASSWORD='apple'
GO
```

There is no default domain password policy in SQL Server. That's your Windows setting which will be set by some group policy if it's a domain joined machine and you're logged in with a domain account. If you're changing it on the local Windows machine using secpol.msc, it's probably overwritten by domain group policy. You need to change the domain policy which means you need to be have appropriate domain level privileges (e.g. domain admin).